# ¿Por qué la imagen que puse con su subdirectorio no se muestra en la pantalla interaciva que estoy programando al correr mi codigo?

Tags: python

```
import sys
import pygame

ANCHO = 640
ALTO = 480

class Bolita (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:/pygame/imagenes/bolita.png')
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))

pygame.display.set_caption('Juego de ladrillos')

bolita = Bolita()

while True:

    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if  evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    
    


pantalla.blit(bolita.image, bolita.rect)

pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que usas `_init_` con solo un guión bajo en lugar de dos. Entonces, la función de inicialización de `Bolita` no se ejecuta nunca.

Tienes que cambiar estas dos líneas:

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

Recuerda que todos estos métodos mágicos tienes dos guiones bajo por cada lado.

Comment: En mi código en mi lector de texto si usé los doble guión bajo pero cuando lo copié y pegué en mi pregunta en esta plataforma, se eliminó uno de ellos, pero gracias por ese dato, no tenía muy claro el porqué se usaban dos guión bajo